# Possible for regular users to create secrets that cannot be read by Vault admins?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Is it possible (perhaps with response wrapping?) for ordinary users to create secrets that only they (and not Vault admins) can read?

Cubbyholes seem promising.
"no token can access another token's cubbyhole"
https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/cubbyhole/index.html

On the other hand, it's not clear if root tokens trump cubbyholes.
"Root tokens can do anything in Vault. Anything." -- 
https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/tokens.html

Answer (score 0):

Regarding root token: as you already have found, vault root tokens can do anything in Vault, as they have the root policy attached. The best way is to revoke the root token after vault initial setup and then, only if needed, generate new root token on-the-fly:

> the Vault team recommends that root tokens are only used for just enough initial setup (usually, setting up authentication backends and policies necessary to allow administrators to acquire more limited tokens) or in emergencies, and are revoked immediately after they are no longer needed. If a new root token is needed, the generate-root command and associated API endpoint can be used to generate one on-the-fly.

---

Regarding Cubbyhole: this backend works like a unique namespace for **each** token. Destroying the token deletes all the data stored in its cubbyhole space.

You may think about like that: only client has additional (read as `another`) token

> A new single-use token is generated with a TTL as supplied by the client

and **only** that token provides access to cubbyhole storage. From [Cubbyhole authentication principles](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/cubbyhole-authentication-principles/):

> The cubbyhole backend is a simple filesystem abstraction similar to the generic backend (which is mounted by default at secret/) with one important twist: the entire filesystem is scoped to a single token and is completely inaccessible to any other token.

In other words, it does not matter, what policies attached to the token, but matter what the token is themselves. And only a **single** token can be used to set or retrieve values in its cubbyhole.

Comment: So.... Can someone with the root token access cubbyhole storage or not?